# How do you display a formatted Word Doc in HTML/PHP?

Tags: php, ms-word, openxml, doc

What is the best way to display a formatted Word Doc in HTML/PHP?

Here is the code I currently have but it doesn't format it:

```
$word = new COM("word.application") or die ("Could not initialise MS Word object.");
$word->Documents->Open(realpath("ACME.doc"));

// Extract content.
$content = (string) $word->ActiveDocument->Content;

echo $content;

$word->ActiveDocument->Close(false);

$word->Quit();
$word = null;
unset($word);
```

Comment: I'm hoping lol... The code I posted works but again it doesn't format it in anyway.

Comment: You would need some software that could parse the Word formatting grammer and convert it to HTML and CSS.

Comment: Office Automation on a server (or any unattended environment) is not safe or recommended and inherently single-use.  Do not do this on a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know nothing about COM, but poking around the Word API docs on MSDN, it looks like your best bet is going to be using [`Document.SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas.aspx) to save as [`wsFormatFilteredHTML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdsaveformat.aspx) to a temporary file, then serving that HTML to the user.  Be sure to pick the *filtered* HTML, otherwise you're going to get the soupiest tag soup *ever*.

Comment: Not able to get this working... Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: That's all I've got, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

I figured this out. Check out the solution to reading a Word Doc and formatting it in HTML:

```
$filename = "ACME.doc";
$word = new COM("word.application") or die ("Could not initialise MS Word object.");
$word->Documents->Open(realpath($filename));

$new_filename = substr($filename,0,-4) . ".html";

// the '2' parameter specifies saving in txt format
// the '6' parameter specifies saving in rtf format
// the '8' parameter specifies saving in html format
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs("C:/a1/projects/---full path--- /".$new_filename,8);
$word->Documents[1]->Close(false);
$word->Quit();
//$word->Release();
$word = NULL;
unset($word);

$fh = fopen($new_filename, 'r');
$contents = fread($fh, filesize($new_filename));
echo $contents;
fclose($fh);
//unlink($new_filename);
```

Couple of things... Having "charset=UTF-8" at the top of my PHP page was adding a bunch of diamonds with questions marks... I deleted that and it works perfectly.

Also, the SaveAs has to have the full path, at least locally, I added that to get it to work.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I needed correct XHTML, which Office won't give you (I do *not* understand that). You can use tools such as JTidy or TagSoup to fix the HTML, if you need to. Cf. http://slideguitarist.blogspot.com/2011/03/exporting-word-documents-to-html.html