# I need to view the docx file from mysql database on screen and highlight the keyword

Tags: php

I would like to ask could I collect the doxc file that i had upload before and display only on screen but not download and also i would like to highlight the keywords? I have successfully upload and download the docx file and it look prefect. But how if I would like to just display on screen in php or html format and highlight the keyword. The problem I got now is when I collect the docx file from mysql and echo on page it gave me all messy words and I've try a lot of methods still couldn't get the docx file print on screen. Anyone please help me, I'm totally lost and hopeless...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334301/how-do-you-display-a-formatted-word-doc-in-html-php

Answer (score 0):

Through html you can do an

```
<a href="file location">
```

and it will display the file on-screen. I'm not sure on .docx though-certain file types not supported by the browser will promt a download and not display.

Comment: Thx Jhaasie77, The problems I found is I can't display the docx file from mysql database. When I retrieved it from mysql database I can download it. But I need to display it rather than downlaod it. Any idea please? Thx.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm sure there is a way to convert the blob data type back to text, but If you want to preserve all of the formatting and everything you could retreive it from the server, store it in a temp folder, and then use the html tag to link it.
Here is a helpful site for that: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx

Comment: Also the reason why everything looks crazy when you echo the contents of the file is because of how mysql stores the file.